# Why the system information message when accessing an Ubuntu server doesn't match free -m?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, memory, swap

Each time I SSH into my AWS Ubuntu servers I see a system information message, showing load, memory usage and packages available to install, like this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-51-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sun Nov 10 18:06:43 EST 2013

  System load:  0.08              Processes:           127
  Usage of /:   4.9% of 98.43GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 69%               IP address for eth0: 10.236.136.233
  Swap usage:   100%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

13 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest
  http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

Use Juju to deploy your cloud instances and workloads.
  https://juju.ubuntu.com/#cloud-precise
*** /dev/xvda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***

*** System restart required ***
```

My question is about the memory percentage shown. In this case, it's showing a 69% of memory usage, but since the swap usage was 100% I checked it by myself. So when I run `free -m` I get this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1652       1635         17          0          4         29
-/+ buffers/cache:       1601         51
Swap:          895        895          0
```

And that's of course closer to 100% than to 69%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

system info comes from "landscape-sysinfo" binary which takes the metrics from /proc/meminfo for memory which is also the source for free command as well, so ultimately they should match. For ubuntu 12.04.3 though there was a bug for "ladnscape-sysinfo" where it was not calculating utilization correctly, you might still have it on you OS:

source bug:  [landscape-sysinfo bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/landscape-client/+bug/1075619)