# How to configure the login message in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, login, motd

Each time I SSH into my AWS Ubuntu servers I see a system information message, showing load, memory usage and packages available to install, like this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-51-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sun Nov 10 18:06:43 EST 2013

  System load:  0.08              Processes:           127
  Usage of /:   4.9% of 98.43GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 69%               IP address for eth0: 10.236.136.233
  Swap usage:   100%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

13 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest
  http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

Use Juju to deploy your cloud instances and workloads.
  https://juju.ubuntu.com/#cloud-precise
*** /dev/xvda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***

*** System restart required ***
```

My question is, how is that message created? How can I configure it?

Comment: To hide it [you can just `touch ~/.hushlogin`](https://debian-administration.org/article/546/Giving_yourself_a_quieter_SSH_login)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This login message is created by Ubuntu's `landscape` packages. Speaking personally, I think they're quite annoying and as such, have configured ansible to nuke those packages and set a blank login message.

To do that:

```
$ apt-get remove landscape-client landscape-common 
$ rm -f /etc/motd && touch /etc/motd
```

That will create a blank `/etc/motd`. To set a custom login message, edit that file as desired.

Comment: Thank you @EEAA, that was helpful. Maybe you'll be able to help me with a related question http://serverfault.com/questions/554021/why-the-system-information-message-when-accessing-an-ubuntu-server-doesnt-match?rq=1

Comment: @Andres Sorry, I have no idea. As mentioned in my answer, I disable these login messages. I figure my monitoring system will tell me if there are any issues with regards to CPU or memory.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had to clear `/etc/update-motd.d/51-cloudguest`, which read:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This file is written by the Ubuntu image build process, it is not
# managed by a package.  If you want to avoid seeing this advertisement,
# then you can safely remove the file.
echo ""
echo "  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:"
echo "    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud"
echo ""
echo "  Use Juju to deploy your cloud instances and workloads:"
echo "    https://juju.ubuntu.com/#cloud-saucy"
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "had to clear"? Do you delete the file '51-cloudguest' completely or do you just delete the entire content in the file?

Comment: IIRC I left the file there but deleted the contents

Comment: I ask because the header says: "if you want to avoid seeing this advertisement then you can safely remove the file."

Comment: @PeterCo Fair enough. I guess I figured keeping it there wouldn't hurt and still achieve the same result

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered, I'd like to add a different approach: Since I find (many of the) dynamically generated infos quite useful, I prefer to not delete the entire motd or uninstall the landscape package, because I am not doing this administation stuff every day.

Ubuntu stores dynamic motd in "/etc/update-motd.d/" folder. So, to disable entire motd, just remove eXecute permissions on the respective scripts:

```
    $ sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/*
```

or do this on a per script basis, e.g.

```
    $ sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text
```

in order to just disable a single section (e.g. the help-text). You get the section back by issuing the `chmod +x` command. See the description in [Disable dynamic motd and news on Ubuntu ...](https://linuxconfig.org/disable-dynamic-motd-and-news-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

You can also shrink the quite lengthy "System information" output to fit your needs, e.g.

```
System information as of Mon 27 Dec 2021 05:26:42 PM CET

IPv4 address for enp3s0: 192.168.0.10   Temperature: 36.0 C
```

by adding a config section to the `/etc/landscape/client.conf` file:

```
[sysinfo]
sysinfo_plugins = Network, Temperature
```

See the `landscape-sysinfo(1)` man page for details about that config.

Hope this helps.